# Database design for workout tracking app. How do I model relation for exercise stats to a routine?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, backend

I am practicing working with relational databases and am having problems with my database design. I am making a web application that tracks a users workouts at the gym. Each user should be able to have multiple routines. A routine can have multiple exercises. Each exercise has stats for that specific routine. Also, the user can favorite an exercise and keep track of the highest weight lifted. I am not sure how to store the stats for the exercise for a specific routine and not the exercise itself. Here is the link to my figma design and it will be what my app should look like on a mobile screen. Hopefully it gives more context. https://www.figma.com/file/lzjYLFfqDBux4J5Clyjg7E/Exercise-Tracker?node-id=0%3A1

[image: database design]

Comment: I think your design just needs a favourite column in exercise. If you are aiming for higher normalisation then you can also create a favourite table and map user id and exercise id. For highest weight, you can add trigger that will take weight in stats to exercise table but also add constraint on exercise table that can only allow the update if value is greater than current. (Default will be 0 for new users). Also trigger should be written with try catch error handling or it will fail. Maybe this approach will work?

Comment: Since there is a join path to the routine from the stats, you are already storing it against the routine. That's one of the features of the relational model.

Comment: @ShamvilKazmi I have a "favorited" column in the exercise table. I will write some logic to check if the weight lifted is greater than the heaviest weight column on the exercise and update it accordingly.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Okay that is good to know. So I don't have to make any other changes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more to this than I mentioned in my comment.

Consider: should `exercise` be a unique list of exercises? Should "arm curl" only appear in this list once?

In your current data model, if you have *arm curl* in two different routines, you need two *arm curl* records in `exercise` which is probably not what you want.

It seems like there is a many to many between `exercise` and `routine`

One `exercise`, *arm curl* can be in multiple `routine`.  One `routine` can have many `exercise`. So you need a bridge table between the two

This way you can just store a single "arm curl" in `exercise`

Then your `stats` table would need to join through the bridge table instead.

If you want to analyse your arm curls over different routines (and in fact different users) then it should be unique in this table

With regards to storing `highest_weight`. Typically you would not explicitly store and maintain summaries like this. Instead you run a query across the data when the user is interested in it. Only when you have a performance issue due to lots of records (maybe 100k in stats)do you start considering these pre calced statistics.